# ERROR context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed

Tags: java, grails

I upgrade project from 1.3.7 to 2.2.1 in my GGTS.When run project I got the error following:

```
| Error 2013-07-26 13:28:09,778 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2013-07-26 13:28:09,819 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;
Message: org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: did you tried 'run grails compile --refresh-dependencies' and did you posted complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem in GGTS after having upgraded a project. Try to launch the project using a command line:

```
grails run-app
```

If it worked then you have to upgrade [GGTS](http://grails.org/products/ggts) itself to the last version.

Comment: when i run app from command line , i am getting this  Error Error loading plugin manager: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/support/PropertyTypeDescriptor

Comment: I solved this error. Again the ERROR context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed came when run grails through command.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the open jdk. i installed oracle jdk and jre then i could run the application without any problem